# Unable to CloudFront Create Invalidation [ AWS PHP SDK 3.X ]

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

Unable to understand what mistake i doing while invalidating Cloud front resource using AWS PHP SDK Version 3,

**My Code**

```
 public function cfCreateInvalidation()
    {
        $item = "http://mycdn.domain.com/resourcepath?queryString" ;
        try {
            $data = [
                'DistributionId' => 'ActualValueHereID',
                'InvalidationBatch' => [
                    'CallerReference' => '16 Char Random String',
                    'Paths' => [
                        'Items' => [$item],
                        'Quantity' => 1,
                    ],
                ]
            ];

            $result = $this->cloudFrontConnection->createInvalidation($data);

        }catch (\Exception $exception) {
            echo json_encode($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Every time I am getting:**

```
Error executing "CreateInvalidation" on "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2017-03-25/distribution/AAABBBBCCCCD/invalidation"; 
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2017-03-25/distribution/AAABBBBCCCCD/invalidation` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2017-03-25/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type>< (truncated...)
 MalformedInput (client): Could not parse XML - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2017-03-25/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>MalformedInput</Code><Message>Could not parse XML</Message></Error><RequestId>ad9b467c-211e-11e8-ba32-45e52ff9e8b3</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests there may be other issues as well, but your `$item` expects a **path**, rather than a URL.

`/resourcepath*` is expected, here.  All cached objects for the specified path will be invalidated, regardless of scheme, method, headers, or cookies that may also be part of the cache key.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects-paths) seems ambiguous, but suggests that the `*` at the end is needed to catch query strings if your distribution is configured to cache on them. (The `*` matches 0 or more characters).  There is no documented example of actually including the query string in the path you submit.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem with a Wordpress plugin that handles cleaning cache when updating published posts.

When calling createInvalidation($data) (the $data structure is the same in post question) I got that error

> AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST
>   https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2017-10-30/distribution/E3QES3NJL8EBYN/invalidation`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request`

(that could only be retrieved on log error file while the page output was the generic one

"Access Denied"...)

Reading the CloudFront documentation I found out that the createInvalidation method has its asyncronous version that is: 
  **createInvalidationAsync($data)**

You can do this for every CloudFront method indeed as it is written in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cloudfront-2016-01-28.html (appending the Async word to the operation name)

With this one all is working properly and no error is retrieved because the system returns an "ok I'll do it soon later" response and all the process of publication post can be carried out with success.

I know this is a workaround because this doesn't eliminate the root cause of the problem  but it is working for me and I hope this could help anyone.